# sDNA - randomization

Tags: shortest-path, sdna

I am working on a pedestrian flow model for an inner city area using sDNA and link-weighted betweenness. The network is a slightly simplified road centerline map (not OSM) where most pedestrian streets are represented by a centerline.
I am getting good correlations with gate counts with the Pedestrian (hybrid) model at 600 m and 600 m + 1000 m (banded) but I noticed that adding a random component (linerand=1; juncrand=1, no oversampling specified) increases the r2 in some cases, especially for counts in the very center (where flows are likely more randomly distributed than along streets leading into the center).

The question is now, what does this randomization factor "rand" actually do? Since rand is added the formula as a factor to link and junction distances, I assume it randomly increases or decreases distances of some links and junctions to generate alternative shortest paths. The values drawn for rand are constrained to 0.1 and 10 - does that mean that a factor of up to 10 can applied to distance in a few cases? That seems a lot, so there is likely something here I did not fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

`linerand` and `juncrand`, as you say, apply a random scaling factor to the distance of links and junctions. The random variable has normal distribution, with mean 1 and the standard deviation you supply (in your example above, also 1). So 99.85% of the time, with a standard deviation of 1, the variable will be less than 4; 97.5% of the time it will be under 3; 84% of the time it will be under 2. The truncation between 0.1 and 10 is just there to catch extreme values (particularly zero- or negative weights which you probably don't want).

Also note that the random value is redrawn for each polyline and junction, when computing each origin. Because it is per-line, the overall effect on the route is smoothed out. And overall the tendency of trips from certain origins to avoid/be attracted to certain routes will also be cancelled out by other origins, resulting in a further smoothing effect overall between similar paths assuming you have lots of origins. If you apply oversampling it will smooth again by computing trips from each origin multiple times, each time drawing new random samples.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the excellent response - makes perfect sense!